# No reputation points for editing

Tags: bug, reputation, edits

I have over 3k reputation on stackoverflow. I have edited few questions but i never got any reputation from it. Is there any restriction on who gets the reputation from edit?

Comment: I am pretty sure you cannot receive the rep once you reach 2k.

Comment: You get 2 rep points for approved edits you suggest untill you reach 2k.

Answer (score 6):

After you reach 2000 reputation, you no longer recieve reputation from editing. This is because your edits no longer have to be reviewed; they are applied immediately.

When you have less than 2000 reputation, other users review your edits in the suggested edit queue, and you gain rep when they're approved.

See [the privilege page for editing others' posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

These reputations bonuses are gone once you don't have to go through the edit review queue anymore.

The `+2` was awarded for having one of your reviews accepted.

Comment: i have 1700+ reputation, but i am not getting reputation on editing why?

Comment: because you already edited 500 questions probably